# Why bootstrap 4 modal did not showing navbar ul li a instance using iframe?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, bootstrap-4

i am trying to view html in bootstrap 4 modal, it show every things but not showing navbar ul li a! why this happen? i could not find any solution out there please help me! 
(*i want modal full screen*)

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelId">
    Launch
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modelId" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
     
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>
          <iframe name="iframe1" width="100%" height="820px" src="home.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried on my computer and it works fine.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelId">
  Launch
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="modelId" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">

    <div class="modal-content">

      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
          <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
          </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <iframe name="iframe1" width="100%" height="820px" src="https://nishargshah.com" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
  
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your `home.html` exists and is accessible.
You should add a `<div class="modal-body">` component to wrap your iframe like so :

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modelId">
    Launch
  </button>
  
  <!-- Modal -->
  <div class="modal fade" id="modelId" tabindex="" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="modelTitleId" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-xl" role="document">
     
      <div class="modal-content">

        <div class="modal-header">
          <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
              <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="modal-body">
          <iframe name="iframe1" width="100%" height="820px" src="home.html" frameborder="1" scrolling="yes"></iframe>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```